# Storing non-serializable bean vaadin

Tags: java, spring, websphere, vaadin

i've moved from 7.7.9 to 7.7.30 and in the log I see a series of:

```
2022-01-26T18:55:20.767;W;com.vaadin.spring.internal.BeanStore;Storing non-serializable bean [it.SearchMoldel@7a80a602] 
with name [searchMoldel] in [UIBeanStore[id=db40ec6a, name=UI:0]]
```

It is a warning but I'm asking why and also what does it means?
Also I use vaadin-spring-1.0.2.jar, is that right? Or I have to move to a recent version?

Comment: You might want to run your JVM with the `-Dsun.io.serialization.extendedDebugInfo=true` parameter to make it print some extra debugging info to help pinpoint exactly which class it is that isn't serializable.